# How to read the complete historical records from the ktable after acquiring the kstream on a topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to read the complete data/records from the ktable, but what I have observed is that I can only see the current records i.e. messages that are coming only visible to me and I cannot print all the previous records.

I am trying to print the data to console, using the Printed.sysOut() method.

```
KTable<String, String> kTableMap = builder.table("test_topic");

 kTableMap.toStream().map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(key, value))
      .foreach(new ForeachAction<String, String>() {
        public void apply(String key, String value) {
                System.out.println("From MAP " + key + ": Value " + 
value);
        }
    });

 // Second approach

 System.out.println("Printing to console");     
 builder.table("demo_topic").toStream().print(Printed.toSysOut());
 System.out.println("Printing to console is done");
```

I see no errors when I am processing the stream, but the actual results are not as expected.

Assume that after I acquire the stream I have send two messages as follows:

```
key: test1, Value: demo1
key: test2, value: demo2
```

I could able to see the above messages and able to process them.

After sometime when I sent another two messages as follows:

```
key: test3, value: demo3
 key: test4, value: demo4
```

**I am able to see the above messages as well to the console, but the problem is I could not able to see the initial messages that I have sent.**

Expected results after sending the later two messages:

```
key: test1, value: demo1
key: test2, value: demo2
key: test3, value: demo3
key: test4, value: demo4
```

Comment: I assume the input topic only has one partition (or you're only running one application instance), your group id is unique on each application start, and you're always starting at the earliest offset? Each of these factors is controlling how much data you're seeing

Comment: Are you expecting to see all your previous messages every time a new message arrives?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for. Please let me know how can I see all that information.

Comment: I guess the problem is caching. Try to set the cache size to zero (this would be global) or just to disable caching on a single KTable via `Materialized`). Cf. https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html

Comment: I have tried using the inmemory store which is throwing me exception as org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.InvalidStateStoreException: the state store, my-key-value-store, may have migrated to another instance.